# How to write correct acceptance test for PayPal in-context in Codeception WebDriver?

Tags: codeception, acceptance-testing, paypal

I'm trying to write acceptance test for payment with Paypal Express Checkout with Codeception. The problem is in-context window. How can I switch to that window to fill fields when i don't have window name? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$I->executeInSelenium(function(\Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver $webdriver) {
    $handles = $webdriver->getWindowHandles();
    $last_window = end($handles);
    $webdriver->switchTo()->window($last_window);
});
```